# Is there a way to figure out what files an MXD points to?

Tags: arcgis-engine

Let's say I load up two layers, and then save an .mxd file.  Now I want to get the path names of my layers from the .mxd file.  Is there a way to do this in ArcEngine?

I'm using ArcEngine 10 with VS2010 & C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [MapDocument CoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000500000s1n000000), you can do this (pseudocode, I don't know any .Net languages):

```
void handle_layer(layer, data_sources)
{
    data_layer = layer as IDataLayer
    group_layer = layer as ICompositeLayer

    if (data_layer != null)
    {
       data_sources.Insert(data_layer.DataSourceName.NameString)
    }

    if (group_layer != null)
    {
       layer_count = group_layer.Count
       for (layer_index in 0..layer_count)
       {
          handle_layer(group_layer.Layer[layer_index], data_sources)
       }
    }
}

data_sources = list<string>

mxd = MapDocument as IMapDocument
mxd.Open(filename, "")
map_count = mxd.MapCount
for (map_index in 0..map_count)
{
  map = mxd.Map[map_index]
  layer_count = map.LayerCount
  for (layer_index in 0..layer_count)
  {
    handle_layer(map.Layer[layer_index], data_sources)
  }
}
```

The trick is to get the path string from the `IName` in each data layer.

If you mean you want the path of the original `.lyr` file you used to add the layers to the TOC, no, that information is not stored anywhere in the MXD.